My induction stove only heats up half of my pan?
I have an induction stove but it somehow only gets one half (the left half) of the pan to a high enough temperature. All my pans are from the same brand and I'm fairly certain that the issue lies within the heating element of those pans, because I can rotate the pan and the hot area "changes sides" as well. But is this deliberate? Am I missing some utility function here? Thanks in advance for any advice!

Have you looked at the manual for your one, and does it occur on all elements or just one? We would need to know brand and model to work out if it is a functionality issue or not.

I’m confused by “the heating element of those pans”… pans do not contain heating elements. I’m also confused by “changes sides”: do you mean “changes side of the pan” or “changes side relative to the stove”?

The poster is saying that if you rotate the pan the hot spot follows the pan.

What kind of pan is it?

If the hot spot on your pan follows the pan if you rotate it, and the same thin happens on other rings then there's something wrong with your pan. Place it on the induction and then crouch down and look to see if there's space between part of the pan and the surface, if it's misshapen it could hinder the interaction between your pan and the induction ring. If it's completely flat against the surface then it's likely something wrong in the construction of your pan. Hopefully it's still under warranty.
